# FB like button in tab page application

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I put this line of code in my view:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://localhost:60193/Stories/Details/1" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

as it's in [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button#configurator)

But when I press to like button at first this pops up:

[image]

and when I click to like result is:

[image]

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can´t like a "localhost" link, liked URLs must be accessible in public. In other words, Facebook needs to be able to access it. It does not make any sense to like something that only exists on your computer anyway...